# How do I fix the Attribute Error in my Python OOP register-login system?

Tags: python, oop

So, I am new to using OOP in Python. I am attempting to make a login-register system with OOP where the user registers and logs in with an email and password in which the email address and password are stored in a database table called users.

However, I keep getting an Attribute Error related to the Register Class.

I have used this code for this login-register system, in which I have planned to set the email and password attributes as private.

```
# Class for each user
class User:
    def __init__(self, email, password):
        self.__email = email
        self.__password = password


    @property
    def email(self):
        return self.__email

    @email.setter
    def email(self, email):
        self.__email = email


    @property
    def password(self):
        return self.__password

    @password.setter
    def set_password(self, password):
        self.__password = password


# Child class of User to be used when the user chooses to register
class Register(User):

    conn = sqlite3.connect('test.db')

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(self.__email, self.__password)
        self.authenticated = False

    # Static method that uses the setter from User class to allow the user to enter an email address to register with
    @staticmethod
    def enter_email():
        User.__email = input("Enter a valid email address: \n")
        return User.__email


    # Method in which if the email address entered is valid, the user's account had been authenticated
    def is_email_valid(self,email):
        verified = bool(re.match(r'\b [A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]]+\.[A-Z|a-z]{2,}\b', email))
        if verified == True:
            self.authenticated = True
            return self.authenticated
        else:
            return self.authenticated

    # Static method that uses the setter from User class to allow the user to enter a password to register with
    @staticmethod
    def enter_password():
        print("Passwords must include a mixture of lowercase and capital letters,",
              "a digit, and must have a length of 8 or more.")
        User.__password = input("Enter a password: \n")
        return User.__password

    # Method that validates the password entered
    def check_password(self, password):
        # Checks if the password entered contains at least one digit, making the user enter a new password if there is no digit in the password checked
        if not any(char.isdigit() for char in password):
            print('This password must contain at least 1 digit')
            password = self.enter_password()
            self.check_password(password)

        # Checks if the password entered contains at least one capital letter, making the user enter a new password if there is no capital letter in the password checked
        if not any(char.isupper for char in password):
            print('This password must contain at least 1 capital letter')
            password = self.enter_password()
            self.check_password(password)

        # Checks if the password entered has at least a length of 8 characters, making the user enter a new password if the length is below 8 characters
        if len(password) < 8:
            print('This password must have a length of at least 8 characters')
            password = self.enter_password()
            self.check_password(password)

        # If the user enters a password that fulfils its requirements, the user is asked to re-enter it to confirm the password
        else:
            confirm_password = input("Re-enter password: \n")
            # If the password re-entered is the same as the password entered beforehand, the email address and password is added as a record in the USERS database table
            if confirm_password == password:
                self.add_record(self.enter_email(), password)
                self.conn.close()

            # If the user fails to re-enter the same password 3 times, the user is not registered in the USERS database table and the program exits
            else:
                tries = 1
                while confirm_password != password and tries <= 3:
                    print("Password is not correct \n", f"you have: {tries} of 3 more tries ")
                    confirm_password = input("Re-enter password: ")
                    tries += 1
                print("Unregistered, try again.")
                sys.exit()


    # Method to add the user's email and password as a record in the USERS database table only if their email address had been verified and password had been confirmed
    def add_record(self, email, password):
        index = email.index("@")
        username = email[:index]
        if self.authenticated == True:
            self.conn.execute("INSERT INTO USERS (UserID ,Email, Password) VALUES (?,?, ?)", (email, password))
            self.conn.commit()
            print(f"Account has been registered. \n Welcome {username} ")

        # if the user's email address cannot be verified, the account will not be registered and the program exits
        else:
            print(f"Email cannot be verified,{username} cannot be registered")
            sys.exit()


# Child class of User class that allows the user to login
class Login(User):
    conn = sqlite3.connect('test.db')
    cursor = conn.cursor()

    def __init__(self, email, password):
        super().__init__(email, password)
        self.Found = False

    # Method that takes in the email address and password entered by the user as parameters and checking if they are in the USERS database table
    def check_login(self, email, password):
        try:
            self.cursor.execute("SELECT * from USERS")
            records = self.cursor.fetchall()
            # Searches through each row in the USERS database table for a match of the email and password entered by the user
            for row in records:
                # if found, the user is logged in and can play the game
                if row[1] == email and row[2] == password:
                    self.Found = True
                    print("Login Successful!")

            # if the user's email address and password cannot be found, the user is not able to login to the game and the program closes
            print("Login Unsuccessful!")
            self.cursor.close()
            sys.exit()


        except sqlite3.Error as error:
            print("Failed to read data from table", error)

        # To close the connection to the USERS database table
        finally:
            if self.conn:
                self.conn.close()
                print("Connection to database is closed")
```

In which in the main program, I had allowed the user to choose to login or register here:

```
print("Press 1 to register, Press 2 to login, Press 3 to exit")
choice = int(input())
if choice == 1:
    Register.add_record((Register().is_email_valid(Register.enter_email()))(Register().check_password(Register.enter_password())))
if choice == 2:
   Login.check_login((input("Enter a valid email address: ")), (input("Enter a password: ")))
else:
  choice = int(input())
```

However, I keep getting an attribute error if the user chooses to register shown here:

`super().__init__(self.__email, self.__password) ^^^^^^^^^^^^ AttributeError: 'Register' object has no attribute '_Register__email'`